# Custom Post Type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created my custom post type JOB in wordpress. Also created one role EMPLOYER and assigned it to a user JOB_User. What I wan't is  JOB_User(having role EMPLOYER) should only have access to JOB custom post type. How can I achive this preferably in wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer,
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14553/allow-member-to-have-access-to-custom-post-type-only-permission-to-only-edit-th

You can do this using capabilities with wordpress, use Justin Tadlock's "[Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/)" plugin for adding custom caps & check while writing code if JOB_User having cap in order to access CPT.